# Not able to fetch data from Firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage

I am trying to fetch the data that I saved to the "posts" to the firebase storage but it returns undefined. Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import "./timeline.css"
import {app, db} from "../Authentication/Firebase"
import Post from './Posts/Post'
import Create from './Create/Create'

function Timeline({CurrentPage}) {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState([])
  const [currentUser, setCurrentUser] = useState(null)
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("")


  useEffect(() => {
    app.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      setCurrentUser(user)
    })
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("posts")
        .orderBy("timestamp", "desc")
        .onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            setPosts(
                snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
                    id: doc.id,
                    post: doc.data(),
                }))
            );
        });
  }, []);

  console.log(posts.map((post) => post.content));

  return (
    <div className="timeLine">
      <div className='timeLine__left'>
        <div className='timeline_posts'>
          {CurrentPage === 'Create' && <Create username={currentUser.email}/>}
          {CurrentPage === 'Post' && posts.map((post) => (
            <Post
            user={currentUser.displayName}
            content={post.content}
            caption={post.caption}
            time={post.timestamp}
            />
          ))}
          
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default Timeline
```

I was expecting to get the data that I saved to the posts collection but it does not return any values.